# unexpected error after uploading Shiny App

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have a problem. I wrote app which works fine locally, but when I try to upload it on shiny server in Rstudio I have only one warning:

```
Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
 (Using default: en_US)
```

But when i go to the link I can find there only one line of text:

```
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

I am confused becouse I have no idea what is the problem and how can I solve it. Any ideas? Where I can look for help or information that will help me to find the problem? Maybe some of you were in this same situation and solve it?

Comment: Are you using shinyapps.io? Check the logs for the application in your admin dashboard.

Comment: I have there:
Warning: Error in : shinyjs: V8 package is required to use `extendShinyjs`. Please install it with `install.packages("V8")`.
If you cannot successfully install V8 on your machine, you need to use the `functions` argument.
How can I install package on shinyapps.io? I have it on my computer...

Comment: Try `library(V8)` somewhere in your application code. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/w7s4-zZDJvk